# Inline modification of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given the following list of strings in Python

chars = ['a', 'b', '34', 'c', '2', 'd', '79']

How do you modify this **in- place**, **without** using any external function or any other auxiliary array so the output be:

chars = ['a', 'b', '3', 4', 'c', '2', 'd', '7', '9']

This is a reference to [In-place algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)

Comment: What do you mean by "inline" exactly? And why is that important? Note, not using an auxiliary "array" (assuming you mean *list*) will force you to use mutator methods that will end up resizing the internal buffer anyway, so space complexity will still be O(N), and even worse, time complexity will be quadratic

Comment: Actually I should say in-place, like referenced here [in-place algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)

Comment: Can you address the other questions raised by @juanpa.arrivillaga ? I was wondering the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the simplest *in-place* solution would be something like:

```
chars[:] = [c for cs in chars for c in cs]
```

I suspect this is the fastest, if that is the worry. Note, it is still creating an auxiliary list. Even if you don't the underlying buffer will have to be resized, but this avoid taking that hit in a loop, so at least the time complexity is linear.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: @juanpa.arrivillaga helped improving it**

This should do the trick:

```
a[:] = list("".join(a))
# firstly it converts the list to a string
# ["1", "2", "34"] -> "1234"
# then it converts it back to a list (every char to an element in the list)
# "1234" -> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: Good  solution, but it isn't in-place. It could work in-place by doing `a[:] = list("".join(a))`, of course, an auxiliary list is being created...